# Print a single translated string in non default language

Tags: php, wordpress, localization, translation, gettext

I'm creating a Wordpress theme that will be translated from English into French. I've included all string using Wordpress's gettext functions.

BUT

I want to print the French version of one specific string on the English version of the site, and vice versa. I tried this (on the English version):

```
_e('version française', 'mydomain');
```

but then Poedit complained about a non-ASCII string. So, at present, in the English version I've got

```
_e('French version', 'mydomain');
```

How can I output the French translation of that string, even though the locale is set to use English?

Comment: Get current locale, set desired locale, translate, restore previous locale?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller I can see `get_locale()`, but can I change it on the fly? and how - using `add_filter('locale', 'myfunc');` maybe?

Comment: If there is `get_*`, it usually goes with [`set_locale`](http://php.net/set_locale)

Answer (score 1):

Your error has something to do with character set used for extraction of template. But you problem has not. After all, do you have string 'version française' in your code? Do you want translators to translate this string from english to other languages? No? The use simply echo 'version française'. No translation on already translated string, ok?

If you ever need only English and French translations, your way is ok. But if you need more languages in future, this way it will not work. What about Spanish and Russian version? I suggest to get list of language names in their own languages. And use some kind of drop down menu for language change, where it will have Russian in azbuka, Espanol for Spanish etc. Make it to predefined array away from normal translated files, as language names will be already as they are. People understanding those languages will recognize their own languages anyway. Prefix it with _e('Language: ', 'mydomain'); to be sure.

Comment: Although I actually used (for convenience) the solution proposed by @codearachnid when commenting on his own answer, yours is a very good answer, and more flexible for multiple languages. Mine only needs French and English, but I take your point that 'version française' does not need translation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file encoding for source and file are set properly. Also in poEdit, go to Catalog > Settings and check the properties in the Source Code charset. Try with UTF-8.

Comment: Yes, source file is UTF-8 without BOM, and charset is set to UTF-8 in Poedit.

Comment: Just to add to my above comment, that wasn't the problem.

Comment: I haven't tested this thoroughly and it's an ugly way to do it, but theoretically you could make an "English" translation file and translate only that string using the 'version française' to replace the string. That way when EN is default it only will replace 'French version' string with the encoded string and shouldn't raise an issue as to the non-ascii string